# How to create Panel that supports incremental loading

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I am creating panel that is doing some custom ordering of items. And that part is well documented. But when I have a collection with big number of items, rendering panel for the first time take a lot of time. So in order to fix this issue my idea was to add incremental loading to my panel. But in documentation I cannot find any information what I need to do in order to enable incremental loading in custom made panel. Has anybody add incremental loading in custom made panel? Second idea was to implement virtualization, but I could not find any information about that either.

```
public class TilePanel : Panel
{
    private const double WidthOfTile = 296;
    private const double HeightOfTile = 144;

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        int numberOfColumns = (int)Math.Floor(finalSize.Width / WidthOfTile);

        var children = Children;

        for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
        {

            var item = Children[i];
            x = (i % numberOfColumns) * WidthOfTile;
            y = (i / numberOfColumns) * HeightOfTile;
            var rect = new Rect(new Point(x, y), new Size(WidthOfTile, HeightOfTile));
            item.Arrange(rect);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double numberOfColumns = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / WidthOfTile);
        double numberOfRows = Math.Ceiling(Children.Count / numberOfColumns);

        double width = numberOfColumns * WidthOfTile;

        return new Size(width, numberOfRows * HeightOfTile);
    }
}
```

XAML file:

```
<GridView
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            IncrementalLoadingThreshold="10"
            IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LoadingCollection}">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <controls1:TilePanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DeviceTemplateSelector}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls1:VariableGrid>
```

As you can see control is binded to LoadingCollection that is `IncrementalLoadingCollection`

```
deviceViewModels = new ObservableCollection<WidgetViewModel>();
loadingCollection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<NotifyObservableCollection<WidgetViewModel>, WidgetViewModel>(deviceViewModels, 50);
```

Comment: You don't need to load everything at once if not everything is visible at the same time. As a side-note: If your UI blocks because it takes too long to load, you might find a better way of displaying it or re-use it for a smaller portion of your data.

Comment: A basic approach would look like this: During layouting (measure, arrange) Determine if an element is visible (within the bounds of the parent container). If not - set its visibility to hidden and skip the rest of the layouting for that element.